# Dynamic page based on querystring with friendly urls

Tags: vb.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, friendly-url

Essentially what I want to do is have a few pages that act as templates for data.

If a url is www.site.com/home, I want to query a friendly url field for "/home" which would return

- pageurl (/template1.aspx)
- pageId  (1)

www.site.com/home would be www.site.com/template1.aspx?pageId=1
www.site.com/about would be www.site.com/template2.aspx?pageid=4

Or any suggestions on a better method to do this?

**Edit:**

Also, typing www.site.com/template1.aspx?pageId=1 should route url to www.site.com/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a URL rewriting engine. You can build your own, download some for free or buy some. Here's a few:

- http://urlrewriter.net/ (Free)
- http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html (Free)
- http://www.isapirewrite.com/ (Free and Paid version, this one is my favorite)
- http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx (Free)